# Mutt sending mail without body

Tags: ruby, shell, email, mutt

I am sending mail from a ruby script as shown below -

```
body = File.new "body.html","w"
body.puts "Result body"
cmd = "mutt -e \"set content_type=text/html\" -s \"Automation Result\" -a \"Result.xls\" -- xxx@yyy.com < body.html"
system(cmd)
```

it is sending the mail with attachment but with a blank body.

Strange thing is when I do

> mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "Automation Result" -a
>   "Result.xls" -- xxx@yyy.com < body.html

it sends the email with the attachment and html body. Any idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

Even

```
mail = Mail.new do
  from     'automation_root@bidstalk.com'
  to       'maitreya@bidstalk.com'
  subject  'Hello'
  body     File.read('body.html')
  add_file :filename => 'Result.xls', :content => File.read('Result.xls')
  charset = "UTF-8"
end
```

is sending mails without body.

Comment: Does `body.html` actually exist? What is the output if you change the `body ...` line in your second example to `body File.read('body.html').tap { |s| puts "body.html contents = #{s}" }`? Additionally, have you tested with a plain String, i.e., `body "this is the body"`?

Comment: yup body.html is present which I can view in my browser and as mentioned above - `mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "Automation Result" -a "Result.xls" -- xxx@yyy.com <body.html` works fine. It's only when am running from ruby it's missing body.

Comment: Yes, but did you also run your second example with a simple String, and can you run it with the `.tap` that I gave to verify that the `File.read` part actually yields the contents of body.html? It can still be a working directory issue or something like that, causing it to not find the file.

Comment: Actually I am more interested sending mail using mutt.

Comment: .. The problems are probably related. I find it strange you are not willing to perform some simple tests to identify the problem. I am only trying to help. Anyway, then in your mutt case, can you verify that `puts File.read('body.html')` above the `cmd = ...` line actually prints out the contents of body.html?

Comment: Yes, they are related. I ran your test. Body was empty. Was actually writing it and not closing before sending the mail. Now I did and it works fine. Thanks for your input. it helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I was doing was I was opening the file, writing to it but not closing it before sending the mail so it was basically not saved and was 'null' when I was sending the mail.

just added - 
`body.close` before the mutt statement and it worked fine.